# Pandas Dataframe: split multiple columns into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've a panda dataframe in this format.

```
   Var1                  Var2                        Var2
    A   [2016-09-26, 2016-08-25, 2016-08-06] [u'1', u'5', u'4']
    B   [2016-09-26, 2016-08-25, 2016-08-06] [u'1', u'5', u'4']
```

I want to convert it into the following format.

```
Var1     Var2      Var3
 A    2016-09-26    1
 A    2016-08-25    5
 A    2016-08-06    4
 B    2016-09-26    1
 B    2016-08-25    5
 B    2016-08-06    4
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values in columns `Var2` and `Var3` are in `lists`, you can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) for repeat values by legths by [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and flat values of nested `lists` by `chain`:

```
print (type(df.Var2.iat[0]))
<class 'list'>

print (type(df.Var3.iat[0]))
<class 'list'>

from  itertools import chain

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        "Var1": np.repeat(df.Var1.values, df.Var2.str.len()),
        "Var2": list(chain.from_iterable(df.Var2)),
        "Var3": list(chain.from_iterable(df.Var3))})

print (df1)
  Var1        Var2 Var3
0    A  2016-09-26    1
1    A  2016-08-25    5
2    A  2016-08-06    4
3    B  2016-09-26    1
4    B  2016-08-25    5
5    B  2016-08-06    4
```

Comment: @jazrael: Thanks a lot! This answer perfectly solved my problem.

Comment: Super, glad can help you. And nice day!